# ETH coins did not arrive when transferred from Crypto.com to TradeStation

Tags: ether

I has ETH coins in a crypto.com wallet. I've had a TradeStation securities account for several years and they recently got into crypto. I followed their instructions to transfer ETH. Got the address scanned into crypto.com wallet. It defaulted to Cronos network. TradeStation's instructions never said anything about which network to use.
The ETH have gone form Crypto.com wallet but didn't arrive at my TS wallet. When I contacted support they said I should have used ERC-20 network.
They both blame each other and say there's nothing they can do. It must be somewhere.
I need some advice because the wallet address was correct so TS must have it. They've put m eon the un-allocated funds list, for whatever that's worth...

Comment: Unfortunately there's nothing you could do. The address is controlled by TS so they are the only ones that can access those funds. They don't support the Cronos network so they don't have access currently. The options are trying to escalate the issue so lawyers get involved or wait until they support the cronos network.

Answer (score 0):

Even if they have the right private key, they need to implement and support rescuing funds from other blockchain.

If they insist they can't, there's nothing you can do.